# send perameters to an action method from partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following PartialView and I want to call `Product_Delete` method and send `Product_ID` once I click that link

```
@model IEnumerable<albaraka.Models.ProductTableViewModel>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product_ID)</th>
        ...
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID)</td>
            .....
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Product_Delete","Home", new { idnumber = item.Product_ID })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I have following Action method

```
public ActionResult Product_Delete(string idnumber)
{
    .............. 
}
```

But once I send this `idnumber` getting null in Action Method

How can I bind correct value.

Comment: If you run the fiddler or check the network tab the link should be rendered as /Home/Product_Delete?;length=<<some number.>>. Use the extension method answered by @Stephen-Muecke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendering the `idnumber` as a html attribute, not as a route value. Change it to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Product_Delete", "Home", new { idnumber = item.Product_ID }, null)
```